# Track the same files in multiple repositories

Tags: git, version-control

Let's say I have `repo1` being tracked (it contains .git).

Then, inside of it, I download `project1` from github. This has it's own .git folder (which I might ignore?).

Proceeding, I'll add `project1` to `repo1`.

At this point, I'll say files in `project1` are being tracked by multiple repositories.

I did some tests here without any issues, apparently this situation can be carried on. I can commit in both repositories. Apparently everything is still in order.

Did I forget anything? Is this someway dangerous?

Comment: Read about git submodules

Comment: I read, understood and I don't want to use them here. I think submodules are useful to establish a relationship between repositories (which I don't here). The question welcomes answers presenting possible problems of the presented scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a problem for *Git*.  It may let you confuse *yourself*, and/or let you do things you did not intend.

The key is to keep track of three things: the *repository itself*, the *work-tree* (usually one per repository), and the *index* (for that repository or work-tree).<sup>1</sup>

Git will ignore *all* files within *any* `.git` sub-directories.<sup>2</sup>  You have some top level `repo1` directory (and repository) that contains another directory `project1` (that is its own repository), hence we can be sure that `repo1/project1/.git/HEAD` exists, and `repo1/project1/.git/refs/heads/master` probably exists too; but Git *automatically* ignores them.  However, as you saw, Git *does not* automatically ignore other files.  That is, from within `repo1`, files within `project1`—such as `repo1/project1/README`—are seen as a valid path name `project1/README`, which can be either tracked (in the index for repo1) or untracked (not in that index).

If these files are showing up as untracked, and you try to use `git status` to view them, you will see only the directory-as-a-whole (i.e., `project1/`), unless you ask for `-uall` (or `--untracked-files=all`).  Usually most people hide the entire directory away with a `.gitignore` so that its files neither show up as untracked, nor accidentally get added.

Meanwhile, any time you do an operation while sitting at some level of this nesting hierarchy, the Git "at that level" will catch it.  For instance, if you change your current working directory into `repo1` and run `git status`, you will examine the status with respect to `repo1`, but if you then change it to `project1` and run `git status`, you will examine the status with respect to `project1`.

If `project1` has a subdirectory of its own (`repo1/project1/sub/`) that does *not* have a `.git` directory, operations done in that sub-directory are "in" `project1`.

In other words, unless you give it extra instructions, Git starts from where you are now and checks for `.git`.  If there is none here, it climbs up one directory and tries again.  It repeats until it runs out of possible places to look (there's some special case code to avoid climbing out of a file system, so "possible places" may not continue up to `/`; this is OS-dependent).  Once it finds thae "top level" with a `.git`, it stops climbing.  To see where it stopped, run:

```
$ git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

Wherever it stopped, that's where the work-tree is.<sup>3</sup>  That's usually (but not always) where the repository itself is as well:

```
$ git rev-parse --git-dir
```

(which may show a relative or absolute path).

With this kind of nesting, you will need to be (painfully :-) ) aware of *which* repository you're working with, because each repository—or, more precisely, some work-tree *associated with* the repository, plus the repository and index as necessary—will get touched by various Git commands.  But this "touching" won't inform any inner Git repositories in any way.  For instance, if you run `git checkout otherbranch`, Git will modify files in your current work-tree by switching branches, and then modify the HEAD commit in your current repository.  If this work-tree *overlaps* the work-tree of some *other* repository, and you move yourself into that other repository, suddenly all those (changed) files no longer match your current repository's HEAD commit.

When work-trees overlap like this, people make mistakes.  *Git* won't care; it's just dealing with a repository, a work-tree, and an index.

---

<sup>1</sup>In older versions of Git there is only one work-tree for a repository.  If you use the new `git worktree add`, you can have more than one work-tree, and each will have its own index.  In the special case of having *no* work-tree (footnote 3), there's still one index.

<sup>2</sup>There used to be some security-related issues on systems that folded case, because you could have repositories that had files named `.GiT/hooks/pre-commit` or `somedir/.gIT/hooks/pre-commit` for instance, which would overwrite your top or sub-level repositories' hooks.  Modern Git automatically ignores `.Git`, `.giT`, `.GIt`, and so on as well.

<sup>3</sup>Assuming there is a work-tree at all, that is.  If the repository is "bare" (`core.bare` is set, and not overridden), then there is *no* work-tree and all these questions basically just vanish.

Comment: Given an answer such this, the question might not deserve a -1, at least in respect to the anwer.